# how to get the class name of a statics method belongs to it

Tags: python, class, static-methods

```
class test:
    @staticmethod
    def somefunc():
        pass

a = test.somefunc
```

if I print a, it gives

```
<function __main__.somefunc>
```

where I can not tell which class it belongs to?

Comment: Upgrade to Python 3, where function objects have a `__qualname__` attribute that includes the class name if defined in a class statement.

Comment: @gnebehay Thanks for pointing out, I get the same error as mentioned in the comment of the answer in the other thread: 'function' object has no attribute 'im_class'